# Displaying data from Vuex store in component based on route

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I have the following data in Vuex store:

```
 state: {
    news: [
      { id: 1,  title: "placeholder", text: "Lorem ipsum doloret imes", date: "20-01-2020", type: "management" },
      { id: 2,  title: "Revenue", text: "Lorem ipsum doloret imes", date: "20-01-2020",  type: "management"  }]
}
```

I want to display this data in the component based on the id used in route:

```
 {path: '/news/:id',
   component: () => import('../views/NewsDetail.vue'), 
   props: true
  }
```

In my NewsDetail.vue component I try to retrieve the data like this:

```
<template>
 <p class="display-1 text--primary">{{display.type}}</p>
</template>

<script>
 data () {
    return {
      display: newsId
    }
  },
  created () {
    const newsId = this.$store.state.news.find((newsId) => { return newsId.id == this.$route.params.id})
  }
</script>
```

But I get error that newsId is not defined and that it is defined but never used...
How can I display the data from the vuex store based on route id (that should be matching the id of the entry in store)?

Comment: Not sure how would they help here

Comment: It will be fixed if you change `const newsId` to `this.display` in your `created` lifecycle

Comment: Thanks this worked, it seems so straightforward that it makes me think if this is correct approach for this? Others sugested getters or using computed property which are a bit more work.

Comment: Yes, you should use getters with computed, this would be better way to do this... If `news` was changed in store by another component or something else, your data wouldn't be updated. I also prefer to use getters

Comment: I see, so only do this if Im sure that the data is not going to be changed in th state

Comment: Yes, you can read more information about lifecycles & how they works from here: https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-lifecycle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'error that newsId is not defined'

so what you want is vuex getters

```
<script>
  import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

  computed: {
  ...mapGetters([
    news
  ]),

  newsId() {
    return this.news.find((newsId) => { return newsId.id == this.$route.params.id})
  }
}
```

it's either that or adding newsId to the data object

```
<script>
   data () {
     return {
       newsId: '',
       display: newsId
     }
   },

  created () {
    this.newsId = this.$store.state.news.find((newsId) => { return newsId.id == 
    this.$route.params.id})
}
</script>
```

Comment: So for the second approach I can also set this.display directly without declaring it in data ?

Comment: Also in the first approach can I simply use mapState instead of mapGetters?

Comment: ' I can also set this.display directly without declaring it in data' - No I don't think so but you could try
'mapState instead of mapGetters' - Sure, but you should rather use mapGetters, if you want to make changes to the state use mapActions or install vuex-map-fields package

Answer (score 0):

Your `newsId` constant is defined in the `created()` method and only exists within that scope. It is deleted as soon as the function returns. That's why you're getting the error message--because the const isn't used inside the function, and it's not available to be used anywhere else.

I suggest you create an `id` prop in your NewsDetail component, which will automatically be populated with the ID param. Then use a `computed` property to fetch the appropriate data from the store.

Comment: Yes. In your route config, you have `props: true` which means that route params are automatically bound to props of the same name. Using a prop instead of referencing the route params explicitly in your component decouples your component from the routing and makes it more testable.